# I want to only those names who are having value count > 15 but its giving true and false for all the names

Tags: python, pandas, eda

```
df['player_of_match'].value_counts()>15
```

i am getting this output

```
CH Gayle           True
AB de Villiers     True
MS Dhoni           True

                  ... 
BA Bhatt          False
WPUJC Vaas        False
AD Mascarenhas    False
```

when I am using this code then I am getting :

```
df['player_of_match'].value_counts()
```

```
CH Gayle          21
AB de Villiers    20
MS Dhoni          17
                  ..

BA Bhatt           1
WPUJC Vaas         1
AD Mascarenhas     1
```

But I just want names having count > 15. Please help me in putting conditions.
P.S. new here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```py
df['player_of_match'].value_counts()[df['player_of_match'].value_counts() > 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df[df['player_of_match'].value_counts()>15]
```